# Laravel and @property-write errors in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, laravel-5.3

I'm not sure why I'm seeing this error.  I'm a newbie to the PhpStorm IDE and didn't see these kinds of errors when I was developing in SublimeText2/3.

[image]
The error when I hover over the red text just says `@property-write`

In my Users Model class it looks like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? What are the best practices to fix errors like these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property declared using PHPDoc's `@property-write` tag represents a property that can have **write-only** access outside of the class (i.e. you can write to it/assign new value but cannot read from it).

In your example you are trying to **read** from that property.

https://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/property-write.html

---

> What am I doing wrong?

First of all -- who did generate that `@propert-write mixed $timezone` line in first place?

(*without knowing your project details*)

- Maybe you are using wrong tag (maybe  it meant to be just `@property`)?
- If that tag is correct one then you should not be using this field this way

> What are the best practices to fix errors like these?

The most common fix would be just changing the tag to be `@property` -- it will allow both `write` and `read` access.

---

> I'm a newbie to the PhpStorm IDE and didn't see these kinds of errors when I was developing in SublimeText2/3.

PhpStorm knows more about your code (PHP in this particular case) because of its Inspections. You may also install 3rd party "Php Inspections (EA Extended)" plugin to add even more inspections.